# Vanishing ideal of V($y-x^2$)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ideals

The problem is to describe vanishing ideal $I \in K[x,y]$ of algebraic set V($y-x^2$), where $K$ could be arbitrary field, not necessary algebraically closed.

It's quite obvious in a case of algebraically closed field, because $<y-x^2>$ is prime and one may use Hilbert zeros theorem. 
What about non-algebracially closed situation ?

Comment: What influence does the field have on your method of determining the primality of $(y-x^2)$?

Comment: Primality of (y-x^2) follows by homomorphism: K[x,y] --> K[x] by sending x->x, y->x^2. So, primality doesn't depend on type of K.

Answer (score 1):

**Right answer!**

By definition
$$
V(y-x^2)=\left\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{A}^2_{\mathbb{K}}\mid y-x^2=0\right\},
$$
or in other words $V(y-x^2)$ is the image of the map
$$
\varphi:t\in\mathbb{A}^1_{\mathbb{K}}\to\left(t,t^2\right)\in\mathbb{A}^2_{\mathbb{K}};
$$
the relevant pull-back is the surjective homomorphism of rings:
$$
\varphi^{*}:\mathbb{K}[x,y]\to\mathbb{K}[t]\mid\varphi^{*}(x)=t,\varphi^{*}(y)=t^2,
$$
then:
$$
I\left(V\left(y-x^2\right)\right)=\ker\varphi^{*}\supseteq\left(y-x^2\right).
$$
Because
$$
\dim_{Krull}\mathbb{K}[x,y]=2,\,\text{ht}\left(y-x^2\right)=1,\,\mathbb{K}[x,y]_{\displaystyle/\ker\varphi^{*}}\cong\mathbb{K}[t]
$$
and $\mathbb{K}[t]$ is not a field, $\ker\varphi^{*}$ is not a maximal ideal and then
$$
\ker\varphi^{*}=\left(y-x^2\right)!
$$

---

**Wrong answer!**

A "hand proof" is the following!

If $(y-x^2)$ is not a prime ideal then $y-x^2$ is not an irreducible polynomial, and there exist
\begin{gather*}
a_1y+b_1x+c_1,a_2y+b_2x+c_2\in\mathbb{K}[x,y]\mid y-x^2=(a_1y+b_1x+c_1)(a_2y+b_2x+c_2)\\
y-x^2=a_1a_2y^2+(a_1b_2+a_2b_1)xy+b_1b_2x^2+(a_1c_2+a_2c_1)y+(b_1c_2+b_2c_1)x+c_1c_2\iff\\
\iff\begin{cases}
a_1a_2=0\\
a_1b_2+a_2b_1=0\\
b_1b_2=1\\
a_1c_2+a_2c_1=1\\
b_1c_2+b_2c_1=0\\
c_1c_2=0
\end{cases}
\end{gather*}
and easily one finds a contradiction. *Q.E.D.* $\Box$

Comment: It's quite obvious that (y-x^2) is prime, because the ideal is a kernel of homomorphism : k[x,y] --> k[x], x-->x, y-->x^2. 
But is not the answer to the question.

Comment: For exact: because $(y-x^2)$ is the kernel of the previous *surjective* homorphism *onto an integral domain*. I did not understand your question: sorry; I shall edit my answer!

Comment: Dear Armando, how did you deduce that $ker \varphi^{*}$ generates by (y-x^2) ? It's clear that this ideal lies in the kernel, but why does it generate one ?

Comment: I use a (Krull) dimensional argument, as I had explicit! Now, is it all clean?

Comment: Krull dimension of $K [x,y]$ is equal  2. So, why ideal in question couldn't lies in some other prime ideal?

Comment: Ok! Exactly, what don't you understand? The inclusion $\ker\varphi^{*}\supseteq\left(y-x^2\right)$ or $\text{ht}\ker\varphi^{*}=1=\text{ht}\left(y-x^2\right)\Rightarrow\ker\varphi^{*}=\left(y-x^2\right)$? I remember you that the previous inclusion implies $\text{ht}\ker\varphi^{*}\in\{1,2\}$.

Comment: The second one: ht ker $\varphi^*=1$ ? 
A Priori, we don't know that  ht ker$ \varphi^*=ht (y-x^2)$. Could you explain, please, why is it so ?

Comment: Because $\ker\varphi^{*}$ can not be a maximal ideal, its height is not two (2) and therefore is one (1), as I wrote!

Comment: Dear Armando!
I just didn't see last paragraph of your solution. 
Thank you for your patient !